# Magento fetch an attribute

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a Magento store and got some Televisions inside with an attribute "contrast_ratio".

I need to fetch this attribute from a .phtml file and been trying and following tutorials for 2 days.

Anyone can help please?

I'm running on magento 1.4.2

Comment: please say which .phtml file and which tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('contrast_ratio')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`

Other options include:

`$_product->getAttributeText('contrast_ratio')`

Comment: Oliver this must work, I've used it hundreds of times. Can you confirm that the loaded product object has an attribute which looks like this: **$_product** ? Also which phtml file are you trying to call it out on?

Comment: @Adam - The conventional way would be `$_product->getContrastRatio()`. If another developer were to override that method when you are using `getContrast_ratio()` you would effectively be bypassing their work.

Comment: I can't imagine $_product->getContrast_ratio() would work, Magento would transform the underscores into camelcasing so it would be $_product->getContrastRatio();

Comment: @clockworkgeek, @Aaron James - my mistake     **$_product->getContrastRatio()** would indeed be the only way of that method working, I'll remove it from my original comment.

Comment: I'd try seeing if the attribute is in the model at all with print_r($_product->getData()). You'll see into the internal state of the model that way.

The next thing to do, is to make sure the collection has the attribute loaded, if you have any control over the way the collection is being generated make sure it's adding your contrast_ratio attribute. E.g. try iterating over this collection and see if your attribute is there:
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');

Comment: Hi all.. thanks for the support, I will keep trying your suggestions and get back here soon.
PS: The code worked for "name" and other default attributes. I must be doing something wrong with the attributes themselves.
In the print_r I am seeing my contrast_ratio but nowhere the data and with a "protected" written beside it. This is killing me!

Comment: btw Adam yes I confirm I'm using $_product and I can see the attribute in print_r, but nowhere the data :/
.phtml is a custom made one inside my theme, used to display random products but now gonna change to display according to an attribute

Comment: with the following code I managed to get a bit close to what I want...

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('contrast_ratio', '1,000,000:1');
echo $_product->getContrastRatio();

So I am now thinking that the attribute was not really loaded before.

PS: Is there a way to load a not loaded attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get my desired result.

Apparently my attribute wasn't loaded in my collection so I re-wrote my code and got things done my own way.

My task was to create an attribute "Feature in Category?" so products with a "Yes" would appear prior to the category listing. The field Contrast Ratio was being used as an example.

I'm willing to share this, so here's my code...

Thanks all for your help you led me into the right direction :))

```
<?php

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->setData("product_collection",NULL);
$this->_productCollection = null;
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');

$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
  ->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','short_description','product_url','small_image'))
  ->addAttributeToFilter('seen_first', array('like' => '%1%'))
  ->addCategoryFilter($currentCategory)
  ->load();
  $_collectionSize = sizeof($_products);

?>


<?php if(!sizeof($_products)): ?>
<!--<div class="padder">
<div class="note-msg">
<?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?>
</div>
</div>-->
<?php else: ?>

<?php

// Grid Mode ?>
<div class="listing-type-grid catalog-listing padder"> <!-- the class name will change to .listing-type-cell if viewing in list mode -->

<?php $_items = $_productCollection->getItems();
shuffle($_items); ?>

<div class="price_omg_random_products_container">
<table class="price_omg_random_products" cellspacing="0" class="generic-product-grid" id="product-list-table">
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_products as $_product): ?>
<?php if ($i++%4==0): ?>
<tr>
<?php endif ?>
<td>
<p class="product-image">
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(110, 110); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"/>
</a>
</p>
<h5><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo '<span class="price_omg_random_products_title">'.$this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()).'</span>' ?></a></h5>
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
<!--?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?-->
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php


 ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
<ul class="add-to">

<?php 

echo nl2br($_product->getShortDescription());

 if($_additional = $_product->getAdditionalData()): ?>

    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>

<?


if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<li class="add-to-cart-textlink">
<p>
<?php 
      echo '<span class="price_omg_random_products_price" >&euro;'.number_format($_product->getPrice(), 2, '.', '').'</span>';
?>
<!--<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Info') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><span class="button_info"><?php echo $this->__('Info') ?></span></span></button>-->
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
</p>
<!--<a href="#" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span>Add to Cart</span></a>-->
</li>
<?php else: ?>
<li><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php

if ($i==4) break; // show 4 products max ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
<?php for($i;$i%4!=0;$i++): ?>
<td class="empty-product">&nbsp;</td>
<?php endfor ?>
<?php if ($i%4==0): ?>
</tr>
<?php endif ?>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-list-table')</script>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You have a lot of redundancy. `$_productCollection` is never used except to make `$_items`, which is never used. The collection is loaded twice, once as `getLoadedProductCollection()` and again in your custom `$_products`. You can avoid the whole mess by going to _Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes_ in the admin and turning on _Used in Product Listing_ for "Feature in Category". This will make the original collection contain your attribute without all the extra programming.